# Unconstrained pattern evaluated by a constrained replacement rule

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

I'm working with a notebook that defines `NonCommutativeMultiply` on a defined set of symbols, called `operators`. Semantically, this is a list of objects that have a noncommutative multiplication (operators on a Hilbert space). It also contains a function `CNumberQ` that returns true when its argument does not contain any operator.

```
CNumberQ[expr_] := And @@ (FreeQ[expr, #] & /@ operators);
```

`NonCommutativeMultiply` has, as one of its definitions,

```
x_ ** y_ := x y /; CNumberQ[x] || CNumberQ[y]
```

Even though the replacement rule is constrained, the following pattern

```
x_ ** y_
```

evaluates to

```
x_ y_
```

Why does Mathematica apply a constrained replacement rule to a pattern that is unconstrained? I know I can work around this by using `HoldPattern`, but I could not figure out why this replacement happens by looking at the documentation for rules and patterns.

Comment: probably because `Pattern` and `Blank` are not in the list of `operators`, i.e., `CNumberQ[y_]` evaluates to `True`?

Comment: That could be it. The behaviour still seems counterintuitive to me though, given CNumberQ's intended purpose. Perhaps CNumberQ could be redefined to treat pattern arguments properly? I'm a little new to Mathematica, so do you know if this comes under some common design pattern?

Comment: Samarth, could you post some concrete examples of  `operators`.

Comment: The notebook I'm working with is based on the virasoro.nb notebook [here](http://people.brandeis.edu/~headrick/Mathematica/). Everything relevant to my question is unchanged from virasoro.nb

Comment: Samarth, posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a made-up operator `ncm` (to avoid unprotecting and making changes to `NoncommutativeMultiply`)

This replicates the case in OP:

```
ClearAll[ncm]
operators = {Times, Plus};
CNumberQ[expr_] := And @@ (FreeQ[expr, #] & /@ operators);
x_ ~ ncm ~ y_ := x y /; CNumberQ[x] || CNumberQ[y]
x_~ ncm ~ y_
x_ y_
```

As expected

```
 CNumberQ[y_]
```

> True

and adding `Pattern` in the list `operators`:

```
ClearAll[ncm]
operators = {Times, Plus, Pattern};
x_ ~ ncm ~ y_ := x y /; CNumberQ[x] || CNumberQ[y]
x_~ ncm ~ y_
ncm[x_, y_]
```

Comment: By "operators" in this context I don't mean things like Times and Plus. I mean things that have a noncommutative multiplication (it is clear if one looks at the virasoro.nb notebook, but I'll edit the question accordingly).

Comment: @Samarth, just use your own list for `operators` (this was meant as an  illustration).

Comment: I see. Thanks for the answer! A little follow up: instead of adding `Pattern` to `operators`, which would be semantically incorrect, is there a way to supplement the definition of `CNumberQ` with a special case for a blank or a pattern?

Comment: Samarth, you can use `x_ ** y_ := x y /; (CNumberQ[x] || CNumberQ[y]) && FreeQ[{x, y}, Pattern]` or  define `CNumberQ2` as `CNumberQ2[expr_] := CNumberQ[expr] && FreeQ[expr, Pattern]` and use it instead of  `CnumberQ`, i.e. `x_ ** y_ := x y /; CNumberQ2[x] || CNumberQ2[y]`.